# Universal form submitting function for all forms in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to write a universal jquery function to submit all forms in a table when their submit button is clicked.

What I've got so far is this:

```
<div class="tabelaportes">
                <div class="galltitle">Tabela de Portes de Envio</div>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td class="tdleft">Peso inicial (kg) </td>
                <td class="tdleft">Peso final (kg) </td>
                <td class="tdleft">Valor (&euro;) </td>
                <td class="tdleft">Acção</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdright">
                    1.00 kg
                </td>
                <td class="tdright">
                    2.00 kg
                </td>
                <td class="tdright">
                    3.00 &euro;
                </td>
                <td class="tdright"> 
                    <form method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="kgid" value="34"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="rmkgid" value="Remover"/>
                    </form>
                </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdright">
                    3.00 kg
                </td>
                <td class="tdright">
                    4.00 kg
                </td>
                <td class="tdright">
                    5.00 &euro;
                </td>
                <td class="tdright"> 
                    <form method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="kgid" value="56"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="rmkgid" value="Remover"/>
                    </form>
                </td></tr>
            <tr>
            <form method="post">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="kg_i"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="kg_f"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="kg_p"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="addprice" value="Adicionar"/>
                </td>
                </form>
                </tr>

            </table>
            </div><script>
function submitPortes() {
    var siteurl = window.location.href;
    $("form").submit(function(sp) {
        //get form values
        var submitname = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[type=submit]").attr("name");
        var submitval = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[type=submit]").val();
        var dataString = $(this).serialize() + "&"+ submitname + "="+ submitval;
        console.log("dataString: " + dataString);
        //submit form
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: siteurl,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: siteurl,
                    type:"GET",
                    success: function(portes){
                        //reload page
                        var reloadPortes = $(portes).find("div.tabelaportes table").html();
                        $("div.tabelaportes table").hide().html(reloadPortes).fadeIn("fast");
                        //reload form to add more
                        submitPortes();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
submitPortes();
</script>
```

So, in this case all the forms are in a table. Each row has its own form to remove a row and in the last row, you add rows to the table.
The function submits the forms and reloads the table. 
When removing a row, the function works every time, but when adding a row, it only works the first time. What can I do to make it work every time?
Is it even possible to have one function for all forms?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). Your particular errors include some which could mean the forms aren't inside the table at all.

Comment: I don't see how the html is invalid but the validator doesn't work because it would have to log in first to see this page. anyway, that's not the problem because the function is able to find the form, it writes the dataString correctly in the console (the first time the form is submitted anyway)

Comment: "the validator doesn't work because it would have to log in first" — Change the "Check by" drop down to "text input" then copy/paste the source code.

Comment: ok i validated the code and fixed the errors but the problem i posted about is still happening the same way...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "It only works the first time". but perhaps try registering the event at the table level, so that it will be re-evaluated to include the addition of more form elements.

```
$('#tabelaportes').on('submit', 'form', function(){...});
```

(note: this may not work with your initialization pattern, perhaps move init inside a $(document).ready( function() {}); block?)

Comment: none of this worked. what i mean by "It only works the first time" is exactly that. when i click on the submit button the first time, the form is submitted and the table is reloaded with the new information. when i click the submit button a second time, with new values in the inputs, nothing happens at all, no console.log(), nothing, it's as if the button stops being a button.